# Contextual menu in dojo EnhancedGrid reporting javascript error in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dojo, cross-browser

I am using Dojo 1.8 and its EnhancedGrid. The thing is though it is working properly for IE9, Chrome, FF and so on, it's always reporting "dojo/parser::parse() errorError: Invalid argument." in IE8 when setting over the Grid header. Then any functionality attach to the menu items doesn't work.

I tried removing my custom headerMenu and I used a default one from dojo doc (that it is not doing anything when selecting one of the menu item options), also I tried assigning the headerMenu to the grid once the startup ended and still coming up this error for IE8 (I guess also for IE7).

Any light related to this error?

This is the simplest version of the code that I tried and still giving the error message for IE8. The header menu is showing up one you hit mouse settings over the grid header.

```
var menusObject = new dijit.Menu();
menusObject.id = "myHeaderMenu";
menusObject.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({label: "Header Menu Item 1"}));
menusObject.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({label: "Header Menu Item 2"}));
menusObject.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({label: "Header Menu Item 3"}));

menusObject.startup();

var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    idContainer: "openItems",
    store: postore,
    structure: initLayout(),
    rowSelector: '20px',
    noDataMessage: "There are no itemscurrently",
    plugins: {
        pagination: {
            pageSizes: ["20", "50", "100", "250"],
            description: true,
            sizeSwitch: true,
            pageStepper: true,
            gotoButton: true,
                    /*page step to be displayed*/
            maxPageStep: 4,
                    /*position of the pagination bar*/
            position: "top",
            defaultPageSize:20,
            gotoButton:false
        }, 
        dnd: {
              dndConfig: {}
            }
        ,
        menus: {
            headerMenu:"gridMenu"
            }
      },
    autoHeight: true
},document.createElement('div'));

dojo.byId("openItems").appendChild(grid.domNode);
grid.startup();
```

Comment: It would be difficult to answer your question without the code causing the problem.

Comment: well, I posted the code, but basically this is the very same that we could find in dojo documentation. Any idea?

Comment: This is part of the source code or all the code? Any way check this link and see if you doing similar mixture of html and javascript or in the dojo initialization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865406/dynamically-injected-dojo-widget-not-parsed-in-ie8

Comment: I was reading this post previously, this is the complete code for the test (I removed the code of my app just to check if it was due to something like that). So it is not the same problem, or it could be but internal for dojo when inserting the menu).

Comment: But why not remove dnd since you are not using it?

Comment: I am using it later in the code, but still let's say that someone want to change the order of the columns by Dnd it would be possible. Anyway, I removed this plugin just in case that this was the problem and it is not. I also changed the version of dojo to dojo 1.7 (that it is working correctly in a different app), in this case I am getting the following error: **SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.** 
dojo.js, line 15 character 3286